# Datapicker don't work

Tags: jquery, html, datapicker

I want to make 2 datapickers to work but they don't. I think that everything in my code is ok but I don't know why it's not working.
There is part of my code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script>
  $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Data1 :
    <input type="text" id="datepicker"></td>
<td>Data2 :
    <input type="text" id="datepicker"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<button>Next</button>
</body>
```

Can You tell me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: invalid markup: same ids are repeated. change it to `class` instead of `id` and refer it with a `.` dot in the script above.

Comment: Note: there is no doctype, nor `html` tag.

Comment: Two elements with same ID.. ssilas777 answer is the solution. Work with classes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, *Multiple Id's are Invalid mark up*.

To make this work change the Id to class

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Data1 :
    <input type="text" class="datepicker"></td>
<td>Data2 :
    <input type="text" class="datepicker"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

and change the Jquery selector like this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
      $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: just a code snipped is not good way to answer the question. you can add some details what have you done to make it right?

Comment: @Jai I was not completed, but got submitted in between. Thanks for your time:) Much appreciated

Comment: okay! but make sure to add details always, sometimes such answers get the downvotes too.

Answer (score 2):

use class if you have multiple date field because id is unique to specific element.
try this.

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker"></td>
<input type="text" class="datepicker"></td>

$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/k7zd98yx/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>Data1 :
    <input type="text" id="datepicker"></td>
<td>Data2 :
    <input type="text" id="datepicker"></td>
```

This thing is wrong. You cannot use same ID again and again. If you want to use same thing more than one time use class as below.

```
<td>Data1 :
    <input type="text" class="datepicker"></td>
<td>Data2 :
    <input type="text" class="datepicker"></td>

<script>
  $(function() {
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: and in the script do we need to change something?

Comment: Yes. change #datepicker to .datepicker